# Docker runtime error: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I have a .Net core 6.0 solution with some C# projects, one of which is an application based on the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker` SDK.

Building and running the project on my development environment (on Windows, with Visual Studio) everything works fine.

I can compile a docker image, using a dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "MySolution.sln"

COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "MySolution.sln" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MySolution.sln" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final

# Entrypoint
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
```

When I run the application on the docker image, it crashes, reporting the following error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference`.

Weird enough, I haven't got any (direct) reference to the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` assembly.

I searched around for similar problems, but, of course, I didn't find any useful reply.

How can the problem be solved?

Comment: How about hooking to the different events of AppDomain to try understand what's going on?

Comment: Might be because this is a .NET 6 project ,but you are perhaps depending on a Nuget package with version 7.x

Comment: @ToreNestenius I have no evidence of 7.x nuget packages (see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75885483/1288109 )

Comment: @aybe: the app crashes while starting, before any code of the Main is executed

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that, a unit test project, based on xUnit, also belonged to the same solution.
Removing the unit test project from the solution, everything started to work properly.

Still, the reason why the unit test project made the deployed application crash is not clear to me.

The offending project's .csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```